# Getting error in Angular Reactive form validation

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-formbuilder, angular-validator

I am working on Angular reactive Form validation , where I am not able to validate email .

With every latter typing in email input field I am getting error -

```
ReactiveComponent.html:21 ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.
    at toObservable (forms.js:456)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormControl.asyncValidator (forms.js:444)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (forms.js:2313)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:2286)
    at FormControl.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControl.setValue (forms.js:2624)
    at updateControl (forms.js:1558)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (forms.js:1543)
    at DefaultValueAccessor.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.DefaultValueAccessor._handleInput (forms.js:601)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ReactiveComponent.html:21)
```

> I am putting my code in ts file as well as html file

ts file -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl , FormBuilder, NgForm , Validators} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive',
  templateUrl: './reactive.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reactive.component.css']
})
export class ReactiveComponent implements OnInit {

  signupForm: FormGroup;
  FirstName: string = '';
  LastName: string = '';
  Eamil: string = '';
  Password: string = '';



  constructor(public frmbuilder: FormBuilder) { // formBuilder assign all the formcontrol to formgroup
    this.signupForm = frmbuilder.group({
    fname: ['', Validators.required],  // FormControl  Used to bring input value to the ts file 
    lname: ['', Validators.required],
    Emailid: ['', Validators.required , Validators.email],
    userpassword: ['', Validators.required ]
});


   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  PostData(signupForm: any) {
    console.log(signupForm.controls);
    this.FirstName  = signupForm.controls.fname.value;
    this.LastName  = signupForm.controls.lname.value;
    this.Eamil  = signupForm.controls.Emailid.value;
    this.Password  = signupForm.controls.userpassword.value;

  }
}
```

HTML file ->

> Note -> Button is disabled , after the fields of form will validate
>   button will be enable. I have used Validators.email so ,  if I write a
>   valid email eg - anurag@gmail.com and fill all the inputs , button
>   never enable 
>   **But when I remove Validators.email** and fill all the inputs button is enable

```
<form [formGroup]='signupForm' (ngSubmit)="PostData(signupForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" formControlName='fname'  placeholder="First Name">
  </div>  
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" formControlName='lname' placeholder="last Name">
        </div>  
 <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" formControlName='Emailid' placeholder="Eamil Id">
      </div>  
 <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" formControlName='userpassword' placeholder="your pasword">
          </div>  
 <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Post Data" [disabled]='!signupForm.valid'>
      </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: In your Emailid form change it to: Emailid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you do multiple validation use []

please see -:

```
Emailid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
```

Answer (score 3):

use `[]` for multiple validation .

```
Emailid: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
```

Comment: Or `Validators.compose(Validators.required, Validators.email)`

Comment: @trichetriche
With your approach I am getting error - :  
[tslint] Exceeds maximum line length of 140 (max-line-length)
[ts] Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

Comment: `Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])` sorry, forgot the array. And the first error is your line of code being more than 140 characters.

Comment: @trichetriche I used your approach like : 
fname: ['',Validators.compose(Validators.required , Validators.minLength(4))],

may be my implementation is wrong

Comment: @AnuragRanjan `fname: ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required , Validators.minLength(4)])]`